# Std::multimap equivalent in delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010

I am currently looking for a way to store tuples of a Key (GUID) and several Objects (all of the same type) in a hashmap.

My approach was to define a new generic type like this:

`type TMultiMap<T, V> = TDictonary<T, TObjectList<V>>; //FAILS`,

but this is rejected by the compiler.

Is there a readymade multimap implementaion available in Delphi 2010?
If not, how can I create one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't compile, but this does:

```
type TMultiMap<T, V: class> = class(TDictionary<T, V>);
```

But if you want a "real" multimap instead of building an ad-hoc one, check out [DeHL](http://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/).  It's got several useful container libraries, including a handful of multimap implementations.